# What games would young gods enjoy as "referees"?

Tags: society, gods, games

My "gods" are actually people. However they have access to tech that grants them the ability to do almost anything they wish, plus they have various mind enhancements, so there is little difference between them and "real" gods.
What games would their young play? Real "normal" people also exist in this universe, and I want them to be involved in their games.

I was thinking of something like [Nomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomic) or some [God game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_game)

I would like the game not to be cruel to people in nature, but at the same time entertaining for individuals that can live forever and possess virtually infinite physical and intellectual resources.

So basically I'm looking for games where normal people are the "pawns" and the players are, in fact, the referees. What games might referees find entertaining?

Comment: Not cruel? I think your knowledge of the ancient gods is lacking. They play games like, let's see how many people I can knock up, or what should I turn someone into today. The only rule was that *no god was allowed to undo what another god had done*.

Comment: I think this is opinion based, maybe I think they'd like to create new creatures, but someone else thinks they'd like board games. I would also depend on the person/deity.

Comment: I think the problem Silver is that in the end...they can play anything you want them to...if you have constraints  we may be able to focus things a bit and give you an answer but as its stands I think the real answer is:  A more extreme version of what kids already do.

Comment: I can see moat people reading this question going "I would make some of the questions on this site come true"

Comment: Rather than calling this opinion-based, I'd call it too broad.  And the edits since closing have not narrowed it significantly.  What are the god-like powers that the children can wield?  Are adults for or against this game?  Why or why not?  In particular, if for, what is the purpose of the game to adults?  It's also not clear to me why the children would only play one game.  When I was a kid, I played a variety of games:  hopscotch; hide and go seek; softball; football; soccer; Monopoly; Clue; etc.  Why are these kids only playing one game?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is taken pretty much directly from "[The Ellimist Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ellimist_Chronicles)":

It features a game which is an ultra-realistic "universe simulator", wherein the players (essentially filling the roles of gods) attempt to make their randomly-assigned species the dominant one.  The challenge is that they attempt to do so with the most minor influence possible.

For instance, one player might reduce the cloud cover on his assigned species' planet, to give them a view of the night sky and make them long for the stars.

That player's opponent might make their own assigned species reproduce faster, which would cause overcrowding and starvation, and give them extreme motivation to venture beyond their own planet.

This would definitely be a "god game", but the gods could easily tell themselves that it's not cruel because of the immense time scale involved.  Individual mortals would be unaware of the slight changes and, if they ultimately led to disaster, the young gods could delude themselves into blaming the mortals for their own follies.